# Mobile Testing with Eclipse

Tags: android, spring-mvc, mobile, bootstrap-4, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building a simple web application using Spring Framework in Eclipse.

I'd like to view my web application on a mobile screen to see how my bootstrapping looks (using an emulator or my own device). The application isn't deployed so I'm running it on the localHost.

I've done some research on the topic but a lot of the answers are specific to Android development, which isn't quite what I'm looking for. (I'm just  building  a simple web app). I've  tried Appium Studio, but they seem to require a work email, which I don't have.

What is the most standard why to check how a web application looks on a Smartphone?

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm quite new to software development.

Thanks!

Comment: You can have your PC host over WiFi your site/webapp to a physical device otherwise have you looked at PC browser developer mode mobile view: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/

Comment: @Morrison Chang
Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for :)